# Sa/notre "promo" - spécifique aux grandes écoles ?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, locutions

Quand des gens parlent de *leur promo*, *sa promo* ou *notre promo*, est-ce qu'il est raisonnable de conclure qu'ils ont fait leurs études dans une grande école (où *la promo* est *la promotion d'élèves au titre d'officier*, car il s'agit souvent d'écoles à vocation militaire), ou est-ce que cette expression peut être utilisée aujourd'hui dans le sens plus générique de : *on vient de la même année* ?

Comment: Pas forcément pour les grandes écoles, mais toujours dans un cadre académique.

Comment: @Frank « toujours dans un cadre académique » tu retardes... (voir exemples dans ma réponse)

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Oui, c'est bien possible. Apparemment, tes références sont datées 2023, donc je ne retarde pas encore trop? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le sens de [promo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_(dipl%C3%B4me)) initialement utilisé pour les élèves des grandes écoles d'ingénieurs s'est considérablement étendu.

Actuellement, le terme « promo » s'applique à pratiquement tous les types de cursus post-bac (Grandes écoles, université, BTS,...) quel que soit le domaine (scientifique, littéraire, médecine,...).

Par contre, on n'utilisera pas le mot *promo* dans un autre cadre, comme les études secondaires ou la compétition sportive.

*P.S. : ma réponse s'applique à l'abbréviation "promo" et non à "promotion" dont l'origine est évidemment antérieure*.

Comment: Tu veux dire  que l'abréviation *promo* a été utilisée pour la première fois dans les grandes écoles d'ingénieurs ou que c'est *promotion* qui était originalement réservé à ces écoles ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il me semble avoir entendu que l'école Polytechnique (qui est une école militaire mais également une école prestigieuse d'ingénieurs) serait à l'origine de cette utilisation du terme, mais je n'en jurerais pas. Plausible qu'à la fois les écoles d'officiers et les écoles d'ingénieurs aient copié peu à peu cet usage.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Parler d'école d'ingénieur ou même de grandes écoles d'ingénieur est un anachronisme. On parlait déjà de "promotion + année" au moins deux cents ans avant de parler d'école d'ingénieur et Polytechnique n'est pas à l'origine de *promotion*. On en trouve trace en 1784 pour l'École militaire (créée en 1748) , plus ancienne que Polytechnique (créée en 1795).

Comment: @jlliagre Anachronisme? Ca s'utilise encore, et elles existent encore, même si on parle de les changer.

Comment: @Frank Anachronisme dans l'autre sens. Je voulais juste dire qu'on ne parlait pas de *grande école d'ingénieur* au XIXe siècle alors qu'on disait déjà *camarade de promo*. On les appelait seulement *grandes écoles*. Et puis elles formaient c'est vrai souvent des ingénieurs, mais pas que, par exemple l'École Normale (Sup) couvrait déjà toutes les disciplines.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah ok, bien reçu. Depuis quand on a l'ENS, tient? 1794! Pas mal!

Answer (score 3):

La première occurrence attestée et datée se trouve dans une chanson de  Gaston Moch, 1879 :

> La première ***promo***, sous la Convention, fut rouge.

En 1870, on disait probablement déjà ***promo*** :

> Pour l'une, la promotion du millésime pair, cette couleur est rouge, c'est la ***promo** rouge*; - pour l'autre la couleur est jaune, c'est la ***promo** jaune*.

Source: *[L'argot de l'X : illustré par les X](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k205446n)*, Albert-Levy et G. Pinet, 1894.

Il semble donc que les élèves de l'École polytechnique ont les premiers utilisé cette apocope. Les polytechniciens ont aussi introduit le mot d'argot ***major** (de sa promotion)* qui a perdu son caractère argotique et s'est généralisé depuis.

Sans l'apocope, on trouve des utilisations dès le XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle:

> *Observation communiquée par le comte de Blumenstein, général d'artillerie prussien distingué, et mon **camarade de promotion** dans le corps du génie français, en 1784.*
> Jacques-Antoine de Révéroni Saint-Cyr, *Statique de la guerre*, 1826.

Il s'agit ici de l'École de guerre.

Pour l'utilisation moderne, je rejoins la réponse de [Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53493/1109).

Answer (score 2):

Le mot *promotion* désigne au départ l'élévation collective à un grade ou une dignité de plusieurs personnes. La [quatrième édition du *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/promotion) (1762) cite comme exemple une « promotion de cardinaux », une « promotion de Chevaliers de l'Ordre », une « promotion d'Officiers généraux ». Le sens s'est ensuite généralisé à une élévation qui peut être individuelle.

Lorsqu'il y a eu des écoles qui forment des gens qui reçoivent un titre lorsqu'ils finissent leurs étude, on a naturellement parlé de *promotion* pour l'ensemble des élèves qui ont fini leurs étude la même année, et ont donc fait partie de la même promotion au sens où ils ont obtenu le titre lors de la même cérémonie. Je ne sais pas si le terme est parti d'écoles militaires ou religieuses : a priori je pense que c'est parti d'écoles d'officiers, mais je ne suis pas sûr.

Le terme s'est assez vite généralisé à des écoles dont les élèves sortants n'ont pas d'autre titre qu'« ancien élève de … ». Dans le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*, ce sens n'est explicitement mentionné qu'à partir de la [huitième édition](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/promotion) (1932) et pas dans la [septième](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1280427w/f529.item) (1878), mais ce dictionnaire n'est pas très à jour et l'expression était déjà attestée bien avant.

Le terme *promotion* est particulièrement utilisé dans les écoles militaires (qui font chaque année une promotion d'officiers) et dans les grandes écoles où le titre d'ancien élève est prestigieux : [École Polytechnique](https://programmes.polytechnique.edu/lx/a-propos/diplomes-de-lx), [ENA](https://www.ena.fr/Ecole/Qui-sommes-nous/Histoire/noms-promotions), [Sciences Po](https://www.sciencespo.fr/fr/actualites/felicitations-aux-diplomees-et-diplomes-de-la-promotion-2022)... Il n'est pas spécifique aux écoles d'ingénieur. Il s'est progressivement répandu des écoles prestigieuses vers les écoles moins prestigieuses, et de nos jours beaucoup d'universités l'utilisent pour désigner l'ensemble des gens ayant obtenu le même diplôme la même année. Il commence même à être utilisé dans l'enseignement secondaire ([Bal de promo du Lycée Le Corbusier d'Aubervilliers](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1882153035157486&id=1038294612876670)), mais c'est encore rare.

Assez récemment (je pense que cela date du 21<sup>e</sup> siècle), on s'est (re)mis à parler de *promotion* pour des honneurs attribués collectivement dans des contextes plus larges, même non éducatifs. Par exemple une [promotion de l'Académie d'été de Radio France](https://www.radiofrance.com/promotion-2023-de-lacademie-dete-de-radio-france) désigne l'ensemble des gens qui y ont été stagiaires le même été. Une [promotion de la French Tech Next40/120](https://www.economie.gouv.fr/promotion-2023-french-tech-next40-120-devoilee) désigne un ensemble de start-ups qui ont obtenu un financement du même organisme lors de la même campagne. Une [Promotion Génération Opéra](https://www.generationopera.fr/actualites/promotion-go-2023-2024) désigne l'ensemble des artistes qui ont obtenu une aide au cours de la même campagne.

L'expression « camarade de promotion », de nos jours, désigne quelqu'un qui est sorti de la même école la même année. On l'utilise même pour des formations qui n'utilisent pas habituellement le mot *promotion*, par exemple elle est répandue depuis plus longtemps dans les universités. Historiquement, cette expression est plus ancienne que les écoles et pouvait désigner des gens, par exemple, nommés cardinaux en même temps ([Le Noble, *Le Cibisme*, 1688](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_Oeuvres_de_M_Le_Noble/dGnx4FvWV2AC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22camarade+de+promotion%22&pg=PA18&printsec=frontcover)).

Le mot *promo* est une abbréviation de *promotion* dans tous ses sens : aussi bien pour les diplômés d'une école que dans son sens originel d'une montée en grade individuel (« j'ai eu ma promo[tion] avec une augment'[ation] de 300 balles [monnaie locale] ») et dans le sense d'une réduction de prix (« en promo » = « en promotion » = « à un prix moindre que le prix habituel »). Elle appartient au registre familier.